# Xcode Changing My Capitalization

Tags: cocoa, xcode, text, rendering, capitalization

Sometimes, when I type something in Xcode, it changes the capitalization. For example, I type `psSimpBox`, and it changes to `psSimpbox`. That's OK since it's just a variable, but it is annoying. However, here's a real problem: When I type `stringValue()`, it changes to `StringValue()`. And, so I get a unrecognized selector error.

Also, Xcode has been recently doing a weird thing where my code starts appearing to run into itself. This is annoying, but has never actually broken things before. I don't think these two problems are related, but it seemed worth mentioning. Photo [here](http://twitpic.com/3ohtls/full).

Any ideas for how to fix this? The main problem is the capitalization, but the others would be nice to fix too...

Not sure if this is worth mentioning, but the app is mostly in ASObjC.

Comment: I can't see the photo.. permissions. However my Xcode does weird things when I have a big file with lots of build warnings in it. If I collapse the incode build warnings it stops the code running into itself problem.

Comment: @mackross: I've got less than 1000 lines, including comments. I'm not getting any other errors.    Fixed image.

Comment: Oh right that's something I've not see before sorry :( My problem was different.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you probably have another symbol in your code, e.g. a constant or a global variable, which is spelled `psSimpbox`, and Xcode's code completion is inserting this symbol after you've typed `psSimp`.

Comment: Not the case. It's exactly as I type it; and then, as soon as I compile, it changes. Just that one letter. Autocomplete is playing no role, trust me. I have tested this over multiple projects.

Comment: Do you have any third party utilities installed, e.g. TypeIt4Me or similar ?

Comment: Nope. Again, this doesn't change until I COMPILE the code. This is 100% an Xcode problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the symbol renaming, have you attempted to rebuild the code sense index? Click the project (blue icon) in your project list and press Cmd-I. Click the Rebuild CodeSense Index (or similarly-named) button.

I'm not sure what to tell you about the text running together. I've never seen that before, but I'd suggest selecting a different font (perhaps it's not the default font?) and checking your tab stop settings.

Comment: Didn't fix the symbol renaming. I'll try fonts later (that's not as serious a problem). Thanks for the info, though.